# Syntax error on token in driver.findby Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new to selenium, and i m trying to automate the facebook registration on Google chrome. I have setup eclipse & Chrome driver and have created all the jar files. Now I copied the Xpath of a textbox in facebook page by Inspect Element option and pasted the Xpath of the element as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="email"]]")).sendkeys("user1");
```

But i am getting two errors in this. 1 is The left hand side of an assignment must be variable. 2. is Syntax error on token "email".

I also tried the syntax below:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id="email"]")).sendkeys("user1");
```

But thats not working too. Please let me know what am i missing here.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `"//*[@id='email']"` with single quotations around "email". It should also be `sendKeys` with capital 'K'

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("user1");
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have made the changes. WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='email']")).sendKeys("user1"); didnt work. It threw an error "Type mis match. Cannot convert from void to WebElement" so i wrote,  WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='email']"));
  el.sendKeys("TestUser");
But this didnt locate the textbox properly and type in it. Why do you think?

Comment: That is not valid XPath. Maybe you mean : `//*[@id='email']`

Comment: Even //*[@id='email'] didnt work in my case.. Only CSSSelector works

Comment: Yes... CSSSelector works.. Xpath //*[@id='email'] and //[@id='email'] both are not working.. Do you know any convenient methods to copy the CSSselector of an eliment to the clipboard on Chrome without using any extensions?

Comment: @SivaKumar No, I don't. By the way, you can use `findElement(By.id("email"))`

Comment: @SivaKumar you can do "Copy -> Copy selector" from right click menu in Inspector. Im curious though to know why the XPath version does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try by using this cssSelector:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);        
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.inputtext#email")).sendKeys("abc");
```

Comment: Thank you.. That works!! But why cannot i use xpath and automate? Does it have to be cssSelector?

Comment: there is a lots of alternative to get element. if xpath does not work, u can use cssSelector, or u can use id or u can use classname or u can use name and more. So if u stuck in one, try with others. it is not necessary that u have to use xpath. sometimes it does not give u the exact element.

Comment: Ya got your point.. But how do we know, which is the best locator to use? Does it have to be Trial - error approach or we have any knack of knowing this? I mean is there a technique to use the correct locator or its something that comes with practice?

Comment: CSS is faster and more reliable. All Selenium "best practices" guides I've seen so far advised to prefer CSS over XPATH......and which locator u use, it depends. for example, if the id of ur element is unique, than use by id rather than css or xpath. again if class name is unique, than use class name rather than other locator method.

Comment: Thanks Noor... That was helpful.. I m just a beginner.. Thanks for answering my lame questions

Comment: @Siva Kumar, if u determeined to use xpath, before using sendkey function, use .click() function and than use sendkeys() and check what happens.

Comment: @noor, WebDriver converts CSS Selectors into XPath so it can't possibly be faster

Comment: @KeithTyler, pls give me the link so that i can learn more about this